# Android convert Tiff and PDF files into images to show each page in image view

Tags: android

I'm developing a document signature solution , till now i've succeeded to sign jpg and png ,
but now i faces a problem with tiff and pdf files as i want to convert these files pages into images so i can show each in my ImageView and perform the signing operation .
hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

for converting pdf to images and tiff to images  just check this thread out 
[Convert pdf to image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932163/convert-pdf-to-image-in-android)
[Convert JPEG/PNG image to TIFF image format in android OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278087/convert-jpeg-png-image-to-tiff-image-format-in-android-os)