# Image compression software

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, compression, graphicsmagick

I need an image compression program that works in Linux that is capable of compressing all the major image formats. I need it for my tomcat webserver so if it was a Java implementation, that would be great (I know, not likely). I have looked around and only came across GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick (which are excellent) but are written in C and I only need an application that does compression so they are a bit feature rich for my needs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Aren't a lot of major image formats already compressed?  What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Hi Carl, I'm trying to really shrink the size of the image beyond its normal compression. I don't care about loss of quality. I'm planning for the image to be half the quality of the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to use im4java with GraphicsMagick. im4java is a Java wrapper around the command line for executing image/graphicsMagick commands. GraphicsMagick is capable of reducing the file size of all the major image formats. This combination has worked quite well so far.

Answer (score 1):

They're separate programs, but I recommend:

[pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)
and 
[jpegtran](http://www.ijg.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The Java JRE has support for encoding / decoding images to and from most common formats and no external programs should be necessary.

See [Tiff compression using Java ImageIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281512/tiff-compression-using-java-imageio) for an example.