# Image size increases

Tags: java, image, image-processing, tiff

Using below code to upload an image.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("abc.tiff"));
ImageIO.write(img, "tiff", baos);
img.flush();  
img=null;

byte[] bytes2 = baos.toByteArray();
if(baos != null) {
    baos.flush();
    baos.close();
}

System.out.println("bytes2 size::::" + bytes2.length);
```

My original tiff image size is 119 kb and when I print the bytes of image I get 800974 bytes length.

Why the image size increases? and what can be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your `abc.tiff` file is archived (`TIFF` format has an archived version), while `img` contains non-archived, unpacked data. That is why, your output is `782` kb instead of `119`.

Comment: Not true. `bytes2 ` size is that of an (re)encoded tiff image

Comment: @leonbloy Well, I do not see difference between your and my answer. May be there is the misunderstanding: by term `archived` I meant `compressed`. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You are right in saying that `img` contains a raw image (and hence it's larger), but the OP is not measuring that, he is re-compressing img into a new TIFF (in memory, in `baos`), and measuring that.

Answer (score 0):

TIFF format, as most image formats, support lots of image modes and compression strategies.
`ImageIO.write()` might not be very clever at optimizing, or it might need some tweaking. See eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281512/tiff-compression-using-java-imageio).