# Compressing a multi-page tiff image with lossy jpeg

Tags: java, image, compression, tiff

I need to compress a tif file that has several gray 16bit images (multi-page). I have tried working with ImageIO as here: [Tiff compression using Java ImageIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281512/tiff-compression-using-java-imageio/281619#281619) Initially, each image that will be in the tif file comes from another tiff file. When I want to use the compressors, I have the following options:

1. CCITT RLE, CCITT T.4, CCITT T.6: They give me the error: "javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error writing TIFF file!"
2. LZW. I cannot use it. My images are 16bit and LZW increases the size of 16bit images
3. JPEG. Not possible for 16bit images.
4. ZLIB. It only reduces 10% even if I specify setCompressionQuality(0.0f);
5. PackBits. Does not compress.
6. Deflate. Like ZLIB.
7. EXIF JPEG. It gives me the error: "javax.imageio.IIOException: Old JPEG compression not supported!"

Does any know any other alternative? I saw an apache imaging library but the tif compression only support the above or less options. Does anyone know about JPEG2000 compressor? Any other kind of alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG compresses 16-bit images losslessly. Libraries and utilities are widely available. JPEG2000 has a lossy 16-bit mode, but you'd have to find some software that supports it. [Open JPEG](http://www.openjpeg.org/) might.

However I'd have to ask: what are your criteria for when you have acceptable image quality and when you do not? If it is visual, then you likely end up at normal JPEG anyway, with a good bit less than 8 bits per pixel effective.

Comment: Actually, you make me think if I could just convert directly 16bit to 8bit. If I do it, visually I see fine my images and weigth is reduced. If any needs a code to convert 16bit to 8 bit, just see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the image 16 bit to 8 bit. Consider that you have a byte[] variable plane16 where you have all the pixels of your image.

**Note**: My byte[] plane16 gets the data from a 16bit image but byte is 8bit=1byte. Therefore, 2 elements in row of this array are 2byte = 16bit. That is why I convert it to a short[] before operating. If you start from a short[], ommit "ByteBuffer.wrap(plane16).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts);"

```
byte[] plane16; //Fill it with your image!!!

//Do stuff with imageIO. Set writer and compresion method
ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
TIFFImageWriterSpi tiffspi = new TIFFImageWriterSpi();
javax.imageio.ImageWriter writerIO = tiffspi.createWriterInstance();
ImageWriteParam param = writerIO.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("ZLib");
param.setCompressionQuality(0.5f);
File fOutputFile = new File(route+".tif");
ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(fOutputFile);
writerIO.setOutput(ios);

//Reducing 16bit to 8bit
short[] shorts = new short[plane16.length/2];
ByteBuffer.wrap(plane16).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts);

int max = 0;
int min = 999999;
for (int v = 0; v<shorts.length;v++){
    if (max<shorts[v]) max = shorts[v];
    if (min>shorts[v]) min = shorts[v];
}

double range = 255./(max-min);
byte[] plane8 = new byte[shorts.length];
for (int v = 0; v<plane8.length;v++){
    plane8[v] = (byte) ((shorts[v]+min)*range - 128);   
}                       
//16bit:    
/*BufferedImage convertedGrayscale = new BufferedImage(width,
                            heigth, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);    
  convertedGrayscale.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, width,
                            heigth, shorts);*/

//8bit:
BufferedImage convertedGrayscale = new BufferedImage(width,
                            heigth, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);  
convertedGrayscale.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, width,
                            heigth, plane8);

//Save image
//If you have a stack of images in tiff, do this trick. "image" is the image number you are setting inside the tiff. If you only have 1 image, remove the if and take the expression from the else.
if (image!=0){
    writerIO.writeInsert(image, new IIOImage(convertedGrayscale, null, null), param);                   
}else{
    writerIO.write(null, new IIOImage(convertedGrayscale, null, null), param);
}

//do the next only after the last image to be saved
writerIO.dispose();
ios.flush();
ios.close();
```